# How do I stop MS access breakpoints in vba editor from disappearing after clicking "Compact and Repair Database"?

Tags: vba, ms-access, debugging

I'm new to Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access.

I am developing an application using:

-Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access

MS access breakpoints in vba editor disappear after clicking compact and repair

I've was searching the internet quite a bit in order to determine how I can prevent the aforementioned problem, but I could Not find any solution.

How do I stop MS access breakpoints in vba editor from disappearing after clicking "Compact and Repair Database" ?

Comment: Please describe full problem as this reads as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377): asking for your *y* solution and not actual *x* problem. Why do you need to preserve breakpoints (a debugging tool) and constantly compacting/repairing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Gene is correct.

As a workaround you can use the `Stop` command, which acts like a "permanent" breakpoint.

E.g.

```
If <unexpected error condition that you want to analyze at runtime> Then
    Stop
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

All Breakpoints and Bookmarks will disappear upon executing "Compact and Repair Database". This is a built-in behavior and it cannot be altered.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Stop`, which may be a bit annoying, [have a look](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/assert-method) at `Debug.Assert`, which will allow you to have a 'conditional Stop'